# Integral of $\sec(x)$ using $u$ sub

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I've just begun learning how to integrate and I wanted to see if I could integrate $\sec(x)$ by $u$-substitution. After getting my answer, I was told it couldn't be in complex form, but why, and if so, where did I go wrong? Here is how I did it:
$$\int \sec(x) dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{\cos(x)} dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2i}}dx$$
$$\int \frac{2i}{e^{2ix}+1}dx$$ 
$u=2ix,du=2idx$
$$\int \frac{1}{e^u+1}du$$
$$\int \frac{e^u}{e^u(e^u+1)}du$$
$v=e^u,dv=e^udu$
$$\int \frac{1}{v^2+1}dv$$
$[\arctan(v)]$

$[\arctan(e^u)]$

$\arctan(e^{2ix}) + C$

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Is this right? I was told I couldn't leave my answer in complex form. If so, is that the only answer, or are there other answers?

Comment: $$\int\frac{1}{\cos(x)}dx=\int\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)}dx=\int\frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}dx$$... and we are done.

Comment: I understand that that also works, but is my way wrong? And if not, how can there be 2 very different answers?

Comment: Your solution is incorrect: the error is in going from

$$\int \frac{1}{\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2i}}dx \;\;\;\text{to} \;\;\;\int \frac{2i}{e^{2ix}+1}dx$$ 

you do two things: you moved the $2i$ on top, and multiplied the denominator by $e^{ix}$. However, you need to also multiply the top by $e^{ix}$ as well to maintain equality. Thus the latter integral should be

$$\int \frac{2i \cdot e^{ix}}{e^{2ix}+1}dx$$

Comment: As for whether your overarching method is incorrect, I don't think it is, inherently. But I think you're also making it far more difficult for yourself than is necessary going about it this way, IMO.

Comment: I didn't multiply the denominator, I factored out a $e^{ix}$

Comment: I see the problem, never mind.

Comment: Also, to touch on the matter on why you can't use the complex form ... well, as far I know there's no reason you *can't,* it's just that the original integrand is a function of real values, which outputs values which are also real values. That's generally something I believe we desire in a derivative or antiderivative, i.e. we also want the antiderivative here to be a function of real variables, where $e^{2ix}$ is going to put complex values into the $\tan^{-1}$ function. Not that it's invalid, necessarily, as far as I know, just not desirable.

Comment: There are also two more mistakes. First, that's the wrong complex form for $\cos$; it should just be $\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$, no division by $i$. Second, $v(v+1)=v^2+v$, not $v^2+1$. Fixing all of the mistakes, a correct complex-form antiderivative for $\sec x$ is $-2i\arctan(e^{ix})+C$. Note that the arctangent of a complex number with absolute value $1$ lies on one of the vertical lines with $x$-coordinate $\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ plus a multiple of $\pi$. This is not a very convenient form.

Comment: Hey, just saw this post - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062480/evaluate-integral-of-secx-with-complex-analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from your $3$rd line to the $4$th, you have multiplied the denominator by $e^{ix}$ but not the numerator. Thus, your work after that will not be correct. Also, in general, as the original question is in reals, your final answer should also be only in reals, with this indicating why your final answer can't be correct.

Note I saw that Eevee Trainer just wrote about the mistake in the comments, along with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I didn't multiply the denominator, I factored out a $e^{ix}$

Comment: Where/how exactly did you factor? Because I see no way to interpret the matter otherwise. (And even if you did factor it out, where did it go? It doesn't just disappear.)

Comment: I see the problem, never mind.

Comment: @Jondue Your original denominator was $\frac{e_{ix} + e{-ix}}{2i}$, so to get to $e^{2ix} + 1$, you multiplied by $2i e^{ix}$. However, you only multiplied the numerator by $2i$.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you were unaware there is another great trick to solving this integral:

\begin{align}
 \int \sec(x)\:dx &= \int \sec(x) \cdot \frac{\sec(x) + \tan(x)}{\sec(x) + \tan(x)}\:dx \\
&= \int \frac{\sec^2(x) + \sec(x)\tan(x)}{\sec(x) + \tan(x)}\:dx
\end{align}

Here let $u = \sec(x) + \tan(x) \rightarrow \frac{du}{dx} = \sec(x)\tan(x) + \sec^2(x)$ and thus:

\begin{align}
 \int \sec(x)\:dx &= \int \frac{\sec^2(x) + \sec(x)\tan(x)}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{\sec(x)\tan(x) + \sec^2(x)}\\
&= \int \frac{1}{u}\:du = \ln|u| + C = \ln\left|\sec(x) + \tan(x) \right| + C
\end{align}

Where $C$ is the constant of integration.

Personally, for someone new to integrating this is more of a 'special case' method rather than a formal method. But important to be be aware of nonetheless.